# Apply regex on captured group

Tags: java, regex

I'm new to Java and to regex in particular 
I have a CSV file that look something like :

```
col1,col2,clo3,col4
word1,date1,date2,port1,port2,....some amount of port
word2,date3,date4,
....
```

What I would like is to iterate over each line (I suppose I'll do it with simple for loop) and get all ports back. 
I guess what I need is the fetch every thing after the two dates and look for 
`,(\d+),?` and the group that comes back

My question(s) is :

1) Can it be done with one expression? (meaning, without storing the result in a string and then apply another regex)

2) Can I maybe incorporate the iteration over the lines into the regex?

Comment: @LorenzMeyer sure it does.

Comment: @Maroun I don't know Java, but I just wanted to point out that regular expressions are not the way to go here.

Comment: You can just read it with a `Scanner`, do you have to use regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can be done in one line:

- first remove all non-port terms (those containing a non-digit)
- then split the result of step one on commas

Here's the magic line:

```
String[] ports = line.replaceAll("(^|(?<=,))[^,]*[^,\\d][^,]*(,|$)", "").split(",");
```

The regex says "any term that has a non-digit" where a "term" is a series of characters between start-of-input/comma and comma/end-of-input.

Conveniently, the `split()` method doesn't return trailing blank terms, so no need worry about any trailing commas left after the first replace.

In java 8, you can do it in one line, but things are much more straightforward:

```
List<String> ports = Arrays.stream(line.split(",")).filter(s -> s.matches("\\d+")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This streams the result of a split on commas, then filters out non-all-numeric elements, them collects the result.

---

Some test code:

```
String line = "foo,12-12-12,11111,2222,bar,3333";
String[] ports = line.replaceAll("(^|(?<=,))[^,]*[^,\\d][^,]*(,|$)", "").split(",");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ports));
```

Output:

```
[11111, 2222, 3333]
```

Same output in java 8 for:

```
String line = "foo,12-12-12,11111,2222,bar,3333,baz";
List<String> ports = Arrays.stream(line.split(",")).filter(s -> s.matches("\\d+")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to do it, I will show a few for educational purpose.

I put your input in a `String` just for the example, you will have to read it properly. I also store the results in a `List` and print them at the end:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String source = "col1,col2,clo3,col4" + System.lineSeparator() +  
            "word1,date1,date2,port1,port2,port3" + System.lineSeparator() +  
            "word2,date3,date4";
    List<String> ports = new ArrayList<>();

    // insert code blocks bellow

    System.out.println(ports);
}
```

- Using `Scanner`:

  ```
  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(source);
  scanner.useDelimiter("\\s|,");
  while (scanner.hasNext()) {
      String token = scanner.next();
      if (token.startsWith("port"))
          ports.add(token);
  }
  ```
- Using `String.split`:

  ```
  String[] values = source.split("\\s|,");
  for (String value : values) {
      if (value.startsWith("port"))
          ports.add(value);
  }
  ```
- Using `Pattern`-`Matcher`:

  ```
  Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(port\\d+)").matcher(source);
  while (matcher.find()) {
      ports.add(matcher.group());
  }
  ```

Output:

```
[port1, port2, port3]
```

If you know where the "ports" are located in the file, you can use that info to slightly increase performance by specifying the location and getting a substring.

Comment: this is answer is also great ! , but for my use I had to mark the other one